# Find the difference with the average of duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: table with all the data]

I have a table like in the above image I want to find query for each subject and each movie, difference with the average `median_heart_rate` across all the movies they have seen,  if they have seen several movies and output like this. 
Thank you.

[image: output like this]

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE measures (
    subject_id int,
    movie_id int,
    median_heart_rate decimal,
    movie_score decimal
);

insert into measures values
    (1, 1, 120, 3.5),
    (1, 5, 125, 4),
    (1, 8, 130, 5),
    (2, 1, 75, 4),
    (3, 5, 92, 3.5),
    (4, 8, 72, 2.5),
    (4, 5, 68, 2);
```

Expected results:

```
| subject_id | movie_id | variation |
| ---------- | -------- | --------- |
| 1          | 1        | -5        |
| 1          | 5        | 0         |
| 1          | 8        | 5         |
| 4          | 8        | 2         |
| 4          | 5        | -2        |
```

Comment: And what have you tried???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edited your question to add sample data as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, and expected output as *tabular text*. Please consider doing this yourself next time... This makes it easier for others to help (and saves you from receiving downvotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, this can be solved using window functions:

```
SELECT 
    subject_id,
    movie_id,
    median_heart_rate - avg_median_heart_rate variation
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY subject_id) cnt,
        AVG(median_heart_rate) OVER(PARTITION BY subject_id) avg_median_heart_rate
    FROM measures t
) x WHERE cnt > 1;
```

For each record, the inner query counts how many movies the user has seen and the corresponding average `median_heart_rate. The outer query filters out users that only saw one movive, and compare the rate to the user average.

In **[this demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WTtJX6MQ8DnweWvA1mdKL/1)** with your sample data, this returns:

```
| subject_id | movie_id | variation |
| ---------- | -------- | --------- |
| 1          | 1        | -5        |
| 1          | 5        | 0         |
| 1          | 8        | 5         |
| 4          | 8        | 2         |
| 4          | 5        | -2        |
```

Comment: Welcome @gigahex! I can see that was your first SQL question... Now you know how to ask a good SQL question on Stack Overflow, make good use of that knowledge for the next one. Cheers!

Comment: Sure I will. Thanks a lot for the quick help.